# In HAML w/Ruby, how do I 'loop' a repeating image in a single table column?

Tags: ruby, haml

I have this HAML code for a table.

```
%table
  %thead
    %th Job
    %th Uptime
  %tbody
    - @hw.each do |k,v|
      %tr
        %td=k
        %td
        - v.each do |z|
          - if z=="1"
            %img{src: "images/blue.png"}
          - else
            %img{src: "images/red.png"}
```

The problem is that it's not printing it inside a single column, like I want. I want, in pseudo-code, for each table column to have

job | {repeating-image}

The repeating image part works fine, the columns are also printing out fine, the problem is the images are not printing out inside the matching column. I'm guessing the answer is %td= ??? but I don't know how to put those repeating images in the column and 'add' them to each preceding one (before newline).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your indentation is off, it needs to be this way:

```
    %td
      - v.each do |z|
        - if z=="1"
          %img{src: "images/blue.png"}
        - else
          %img{src: "images/red.png"}
```

Yours was printing an empty `<td>` and the image(s) afterwards.